# PHP json-like-string split

Tags: php, string, split

I have this $str value :

```
[{\"firstname\":\"guest1\",\"lastname\":\"one\",\"age\":\"22\",\"gender\":\"Male\"},{\"firstname\":\"guest2\",\"lastname\":\"two\",\"age\":\"22\",\"gender\":\"Female\"}]
```

I want to split it into the following:

```
firstname:guest1,lastname:one,age:22
firstname:guest2,lastname:two,age:22
```

I tried `explode (",",$str)` , but it explode all using , as delimiter and I don't get what I want

anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 5):

As Josh K points out, that looks suspiciously like a JSON string. Maybe you should do a `json_decode()` on it to get the *actual* data you're looking for, all organized nicely into an array of objects.

**EDIT:** it seems your string is itself wrapped in double quotes `"`, so you'll have to trim those away before you'll be able to decode it as valid JSON:

```
$str_json = trim($str, '"');
$guests = json_decode($str_json);
var_dump($guests);
```

I get this output with the `var_dump()`, so it's definitely valid JSON here:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (4) {
    ["firstname"]=>
    string(6) "guest1"
    ["lastname"]=>
    string(3) "one"
    ["age"]=>
    string(2) "22"
    ["gender"]=>
    string(4) "Male"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (4) {
    ["firstname"]=>
    string(6) "guest2"
    ["lastname"]=>
    string(3) "two"
    ["age"]=>
    string(2) "22"
    ["gender"]=>
    string(6) "Female"
  }
}
```

[JSON (JavaScript Object Notation)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is not [CSV (comma-separated values)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). They're two vastly different data formats, so you can't parse one like the other.

To get your two strings, use a loop to get the keys and values of each object, and then build the strings with those values:

```
foreach ($guests as $guest) {
    $s = array();

    foreach ($guest as $k => $v) {
        if ($k == 'gender') break;
        $s[] = "$k:$v";
    }

    echo implode(',', $s) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
firstname:guest1,lastname:one,age:22
firstname:guest2,lastname:two,age:22
```

(Assuming you do want to exclude the genders for whatever reason; if not, delete the `if ($k == 'gender') break;` line.)

Comment: i get a NULL value.. using the 
$guests = json_decode(stripslashes($str));
var_dump($guests);

Comment: @redcoder: strange. I copied the string from your question and could parse it correctly; could you `var_dump($str);` so I can see what the actual `$str` is?

Comment: ...if it still won't work, try `var_dump(function_exists('json_decode'));`. (Should output `bool(true)`).

Comment: @nikc: I removed the `stripslashes()` call. Also, if the function didn't exist, PHP would throw a fatal error instead of it returning NULL.

Comment: var_dump give these result:

string(171) ""[{\"firstname\":\"guest1\",\"lastname\":\"two\",\"age\":\"22\",\"gender\":\"Male\"},{\"firstname\":\"guest2\",\"lastname\":\"one\",\"age\":\"33\",\"gender\":\"Female\"}]""

Comment: @redcoder: I see it now: the JSON string is enclosed in double quotes. I'll update my answer so it trims off those extra quotes and allows the string to be read as valid JSON.

Comment: in fact var_dump(function_exists('json_decode')); return bool(true)
. so it is a JSON

Comment: @BoltClock : strange enough ... that edited codes still produce NULL

Comment: just to make my problem clearer, here is the code I wrote:

        $str_json = trim($userdetails->other_guests, '"');
        $guests = json_decode($str_json);
        echo "<pre align='left'>";
        var_dump($guests);

        var_dump($userdetails->other_guests);
        echo "</pre>";

Comment: And here is the results:

NULL
string(171) ""[{\"firstname\":\"guest1\",\"lastname\":\"two\",\"age\":\"22\",\"gender\":\"Male\"},{\"firstname\":\"guess2\",\"lastname\":\"one\",\"age\":\"33\",\"gender\":\"Female\"}]""

Comment: @redcoder: try it with `stripslashes()` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

If you split on `,`'s then you will get all the other crap that surrounds it. You would then have to strip that off.

Looks a lot like JSON data to me, where is this string coming from?

Comment: the datatype is string when i use var_dump

Answer (score 0):

If that is valid json, just run it through [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to get a native php array...

Note that you may need to run it through `stripslashes()` first, as it appears you may have `magic_quotes_gpc` set... You can conditionally call it by checking with the function `get_magic_quotes_gpc`:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $_POST['foo'] = stripslashes($_POST['foo']);
}
$array = json_decode($_POST['foo']);
```

Comment: i doubt it is a JSON because the original datatype is string when I use var_dump...

Comment: JSON is an encoding.  It encodes information into a string.  So the original datatype should be string if it's JSON...

Comment: @redcoder: JSON is not an object data type itself. It's a string formatted so that when programs process it, an object is obtained.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **preg_replace** function.

```
    $ptn = "/,\\"gender\\":\\"\w+\\"\}\]?|\\"|\[?\{/";
    $str = "[{\"firstname\":\"guest1\",\"lastname\":\"one\",\"age\":\"22\",\"gender\":\"Male\"},{\"firstname\":\"guest2\",\"lastname\":\"two\",\"age\":\"22\",\"gender\":\"Female\"}]";
    $rpltxt = "";
    echo preg_replace($ptn, $rpltxt, $str);
```

You can the [php regular expression tester](http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm) to test the result.

or use **preg_match_all**

```
$ptn = "/(firstname)\\":\\"(\w+)\\",\\"(lastname)\\":\\"(\w+)\\",\\"(age)\\":\\"(\d+)/";
$str = "[{\"firstname\":\"guest1\",\"lastname\":\"one\",\"age\":\"22\",\"gender\":\"Male\"},{\"firstname\":\"guest2\",\"lastname\":\"two\",\"age\":\"22\",\"gender\":\"Female\"}]";
preg_match_all($ptn, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

i still haven't get a chance to retrieve the JSON :
I var_dump the trimmed value as :

```
$str_json = trim($userdetails->other_guests, '"');
$guests = json_decode($str_json);
var_dump($str_json,$guests);
```

WHERE `$userdetails->other_guests` is the `$str` value I had before...

I get the following output :

```
string(169) "[{\"firstname\":\"guest1\",\"lastname\":\"one\",\"age\":\"22\",\"gender\":\"Male\"},{\"firstname\":\"guest2\",\"lastname\":\"two\",\"age\":\"23\",\"gender\":\"Female\"}]"
NULL
```

This mean the decoded json are NULL... strange

Comment: ooh.. actually i have to decode_jason twice to get the object